# TypeError: Undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.state...map')

Tags: react-native

**In this my code, I got an error which says 'this.state.leader.map' is not a function.

I searched on web about my problem but none of them solved my issue.

This is my code which is below. I hope, code is clear to understand easly**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import DOMParser from 'react-native-html-parser';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class header extends Component {

    state = { leader: [] };

    componentWillMount() {
        fetch('url')
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response;
            }else {
                let error = new Error('Error ');
                error.response = response;
                throw error;
            }
            },
            error => {
                let errmess = new Error(error.message);
                throw errmess;
            })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(leaders => {
            const str = leaders.substring(76);
            const str2 = str.substring(0, str.length - 9);

            this.setState({ leader: str2 });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.setState({ errMessage: error.message });
        });
        }

        renderall() {
            return this.state.leader.map(alb => <Text>{alb.Ref}</Text>  
        }

    render() {

        console.log(this.state.leader);

        return (
            <View>
              {this.renderall()}
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are assigning a string to the value `leader`. You're getting an error because `leader` is no longer an array

Comment: The answers are addressing some other problems, but the @Andrew 's comment is correct

Comment: @hakan can you post the response that you are getting from the `fetch`?

Comment: @Andrew You are right andrew. Actually, it gives me an xml like "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <string xmlns="url">[{"Ref":"IHR1900299","Unvan":"max"},{"Ref":"IHR1900298","Unvan":"max2"}] </string> so I removed before Json and after Json to get just Json object. So u are right I take just a string . How could I solve this then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue is with the fact that you are setting a string to the value of `leader` in your state.

If we look at your code you are taking a substring of `leaders`. To do this `leaders` must be a string. You are then saving that string to your `leader` value in state.

```
 .then(leaders => {
    const str = leaders.substring(76);
    const str2 = str.substring(0, str.length - 9); // <- this is a string

    this.setState({ leader: str2 }); 
  })
```

In your state you are setting `leaders` in the following way

```
state = {
  leaders: [] // <- this is an array
}
```

Individually doing these things are fine, but there is a disconnect between what you are doing in your `fetch` request and what you then want to do in your `renderAll` method as you cannot use `.map` on a string.

```
renderall() {
   return this.state.leader.map(alb => <Text>{alb.Ref}</Text>   
  // .map requires this.state.leader to be an array but you 
  // have now changed it to a string so it won't work
}
```

Either you need to change what you are storing in `leader` in your fetch request so that it is an array. Or you need to change what is happening in your `renderAll` function.

## XML parsing

If your XML is the same as you put in your comment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<string xmlns="url">[{"Ref":"IHR1900299","Unvan":"max"},{"Ref":"IHR1900298","Unvan":"max2"}] </string>
```

Then you could use a simple regex to capture what you want and then use `JSON.parse` to convert it into json.

Once you have your xml as a string, you could do this:

```js
// I'm hardcoding it as a string, because I don't have your api to call.
let xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <string xmlns="url">[{"Ref":"IHR1900299","Unvan":"max"},{"Ref":"IHR1900298","Unvan":"max2"}] </string>';

let jsonString = xmlString.match(/\[.*\]/);
let json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    
console.log(json)
console.log(json[0].Ref)
```

Comment: Actually, it gives me an xml like "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <string xmlns="url">[{"Ref":"IHR1900299","Unvan":"max"},{"Ref":"IHR1900298","Unvan":"max2"}] </string> so I removed before Json and after Json to get just Json object. So u are right I take just a string . How could I solve this then ?

Comment: oh I fixed with adding "const x = JSON.parse(str2); this.setState({ leader: x });"

Comment: @hakan I have added an update to my answer about XML parsing.

Answer (score 1):

React component usual methods (like `componentWillMount` or `render`) are automatically bound to `this` by React, contrary to your custom method `renderAll`. Add the following to your class:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.renderAll = this.renderAll.bind(this);
}
```

Useful links:

- [Docs on the `bind` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)
- [Binding to `this` in React](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56)
- Related question: [React Native: bind and 'this'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48192280)
- Related question: [How to bind(this) when passing a function as a prop in react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43883435)

Answer (score 0):

This happen because the fetch function is asynchronous. So, all you need is to add a simple condition and passing `this`:

```
renderall() {
            return this.state.leader.map(alb => <Text>{alb.Ref}</Text>  
        }

 render() {

        console.log(this.state.leader);

        return (
            <View>
              {
                (this.state.leader?this.state.leader.length>0:false)&&
                this.renderall(this)
              }
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Nope. `this` evaluates to `{}` inside `renderAll` because it's not bound to the component. `this.state.leader` evaluates to the state's leader inside of `render` (which is bound to the component), but not inside of `renderAll`, which is bound to an empty object.

Comment: @NinoFiliu: I think I was wrong just in terms of justification. However this code is always working for me. I have Updated my code. Can you please Kindly tell me your opinion now? Thanks

Comment: It's not that complex but it doesn't fit into a comment - check [this guide on binding this in React](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56) :) It's quite interesting and very useful for debugging React or React Native code.

Answer (score 0):

Your renderAll method needs to return a single JSX element in order to be correct. Additionally I reformatted the method to use arrow functions to avoid all those nasty binding issues. Also: you need to provide a unique key to each of the items.

```
renderall = () => {
  return (
    <View>
     {this.state.leader.map(alb => {
       return <Text key={alb.Ref}>{alb.Ref}</Text>;
     })}
   </View> 
}
```